# Is square wave is an odd function if there is a dc shift?

Tags: functions, fourier-series

Is periodic square wave is an odd function if there is a dc shift?(a0 != 0) And how do I determine whether square wave is odd or not when there is a dc shift.

Comment: Do you have a definition of "odd function" to work with?

Comment: $f(x)$ cannot be an odd function if $f(0) \ne 0$.

Comment: No. I have a square wave which has a dc shift. When calculate its Fourier coefficients a0 gets a value and an becomes zero. I want to know whether it's an odd function?

Comment: @ADG: If "odd function" doesn't even have a meaning to you, then why are you interested in whether you function satisfies this undefined concept?

Comment: Sorry. I know the concept of odd function. If it's symmetric around its origin and f(-x) = -f(x) then f(x) is an odd function. I know if there is no dc shift in the square wave it's odd. But I'm not sure whether its odd or even when there is a dc shift.

Comment: because of the orthogonality of the Fourier series basis, an odd (periodic) function can only be a sum of $sin$ in the Fourier basis : hence no DC, no $\cos$, no phase shift.

Comment: @user1952009 So is it odd or not?

Comment: I can't know what you call the square wave. is it odd ? .... and do you think an odd function plus a DC term can be odd ?

Comment: Sorry everyone this is the square wave I'm asking about.http://postimg.org/image/o109kpx3l/

Comment: I think this is neither even nor odd.

Answer (score 1):

Hint : A funtion is said to be odd if 
$$f(-x)=-f(x)$$ for all x's in the functions domain.

Even with a dc shift the definition remains same and finding whether a function is odd or not by looking its graph has nothing to do with fourier analysis